# Finding folder which does not have certain file Bash (find command)

Tags: bash, directory, find

I have a directory lets say with 10 folder with 9 of them having the file "hello" in it.
Now I want to check in which of them is not the file "hello".

Example:

Folder 1:
File hi

Folder 2: 
File hello

Folder 3:
File hello

...

The find command should tell me: Folder 1 no hello.

I trying with the "find" - command in Bash but not quite got it yet.

Thank you

Comment: Add your `find` command to your question.

Comment: Include sample input/output in your question. I've already posted an answer, but no one knows if it works or not unless you describe the task clearly

Comment: I have given more details hopefully it is more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a loop and a combination of *find* and *grep*, you can get a solution:

```
find . -type d | grep -vE $(sep=; for f in `find . -type f -name hello`; do echo -n ${sep}${f%\/hello}; sep='|'; done)
```

Comment: Thank you I tried that but seems I am doing something wrong.I am in the directory already where all subfolders are with the files in it,do i need to specify more

Comment: @oguz ismail 's answer is better than mine, it should work just fine when you issue it in the directory above the subfolders

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt i am running it in the directory where all the subfolders are..